# What is a word or phrase for student of the year?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests, proverb-requests

I’m looking for a word/phrase similar to student of the year. I’m not using valedictorian, as I think it means student who has highest academic grade. I want to mean something that would mean like best in sports, best in literary contest, best in dance and so on. Please suggest something to me.

Comment: Please be specific: do you want something that means e.g.  "best in sports"? Or do you want some general formulation that covers "best in X"? Or just a general, nonspecific description like "student of the year" itself?

Comment: Are you looking for a word for the award or a word for the student? These types of awards are known as *superlative awards* or simply [*superlatives*](https://blog.treering.com/yearbook-superlatives-ideas-list-seniors/). You could also use *superlative* as a noun to designate the awardee, but that is not very common.

Comment: The most noteworthy student ?

Comment: @alphabet more like general, non specific description. We plan to have different competitions like dance, speech, debate, sports. It could be word/phrase that can suit the victor.

Comment: [Dux](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dux) is a good word for this. It's more of a British English word, but worth spreading more widely.

Answer (score 1):

[Dux](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dux) is a good word for this. It's more of a British English word, but worth spreading more widely.

> X was dux of the class.